# how to do both of them: bold a part of text and message format in android

Tags: android, string, textview, android-textattributes

how to bold a part of text Android String and in parallel use Message format?

I can do the part of the text bold only if the text is fixed,

but I want to use also in Message.format in order to set custom text.

something like that:

```
hello <b>{0}</b>, my name is <b>{1}</b>, my age is <b>{2}</b>....
```

hello **world**, my name is **Josh**, my age is **seven**

Answer (score 0):

Just build your String in HTML and set it:

```
  String array[]={"World","Josh","Seven"};

  String sourceString = "hello <b>"+array[0]+"</b>, my name is <b>"+array[1]+"</b>, my age is <b>"+array[2]+"</b>";

  mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));
```

OP: hello **world**, my name is **Josh**, my age is **seven**

Answer (score 0):

try Html.fromHtml() function on text like below

```
textView.setText("hello"+Html.fromHtml("<b>{0}</b>")+", my name is"+Html.fromHtml("<b>{1}</b>"));
```